# Why is Django admin interface uglier on Chrome?

Tags: css, django, admin

I'm building a website using django.

Here's my question : Why is the admin section style ugly (using chromium and chrome, not firefox) and how to avoid it? The "incognito" mode of both chromium and chrome seems to fix it

Here's a screen of the admin section using chromium: [screen 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rk0R2.png)

Here's a screen of the admin section using chromium in incognito mode : [screen 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51HmC.png)

Comment: Probably the cache. Try to do the force refresh or disable/clear cache.

Comment: Yeah, clear the cache. First one looks like django 1.7 admin, you must have updated recently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the Aamir Adnan and Brobin stated, clearing the cache will solve your issue.